# Listen on port 8080; Tomcat 7, Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I killed my connection to port 8080 via the following command:

TaskKill.exe /PID 4550 /F

Now, when I try and access Tomcat 7 via Eclipse I get the following message:

Nov 12, 2013 10:46:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.catalina.deploy.ApplicationListener@2e264ea7
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.infinitecampus.au.configuration.CampusContextLoaderListener..........

How do I restart port 8080 so it is once again listening to port 8080 so I can run my application via Tomcat?  Thanks!

Comment: Does not look like a problem with a port.  It would look different. I see ClassNotFoundException

Comment: "ClassNotFoundException" is different from a "port in use" error if 8080 were still bound.  Q: Do you see any (Tomcat-related) Java processes out there you should kill?  Q: Do things clear up if you reboot your PC (Draconian, but a good place to start troublshooting)?

Comment: do as @paulsm4 said and if problem is still there try changing the port or complete tomcat directory.